# node_modules error when running a react-native app

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to run a react native app, but upon doing react-native run-ios and opening the app in the simulator, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I'm tried running npm install to no avail. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install this package:

```
npm i @react-native-community/cli
```